# Python count all possible combinations for a table

Tags: python, matrix, combinations, permutation

I have a table that looks like below:

```
   PotA  PotB  PotC  PotD  PotE
A   +     +     +     +     +
B   -     ?     +     +     ?
C   +     +     +     +     +
D   +     -     +     -     +
E   +     +     +     +     +
```

From here, I have to find all the possible combinations of "+","-" and "?" for all combinations of (PotA and PotB), (PotA and PotC), and so on, (PotA, PotB and PotC), and finally to (PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD and PotE). Actually the "Pot" row keeps going on, but here I only show till PotE for simplification.

To do this, first, I read the file like as follows, and then, generate all possible possibilities for a combination of two for count each possibility.

```
def readDatafile():
    filename = ("data.txt")
    infile = open(filename,'r')

    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        print (line)          # just to check the data, need to carry on from here.

"""Generate all possible permutations for later count"""
def doPermutations(items, n):
    if n == 0:
        yield ''
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for base in doPermutations(items, n - 1):
                yield str(items[i]) + str(base)

def makeAllPossibleList():
    nlength      = 2          # This should go outside of the function and will be same as the number of Pots
    lpossibility = ['+', '-', '?']
    litems       = []

    for i in doPermutations(lpossibility, int(nlength)):
        litems.append(i)

    for x in items:
        print (x)             # This generate all the possible items for combination of two
```

So, the end result would be like this:

```
Combination: Possibility Count
PotA, PotB: ++ 3
PotA, PotB: +- 1
PotA, PotB: +? 0
PotA, PotB: -+ 0
PotA, PotB: -- 0
PotA, PotB: -? 1
PotA, PotB: ?+ 0
PotA, PotB: ?- 0
PotA, PotB: ?? 0
PotA, PotC: ...
PotA, PotC: ...
.......
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: +++++ 3
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: ++++- 0
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: ++++? 0
.......
```

Is there any good python method to get the proper logic for this problem?
Do I have to read the data with the headers as keys and columns as value of a list?

I cannot get a proper logic. Please give me some help.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html, especially http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Okay I'm trying to study.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) might be helpful for the counting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're after, how about something like:

```
import itertools
import collections

def read_table(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        header = next(fp).split()
        rows = [line.split()[1:] for line in fp if line.strip()]
        columns = zip(*rows)
    data = dict(zip(header, columns))
    return data

table = read_table("data.txt")
pots = sorted(table)

alphabet = "+-?"
for num in range(2, len(table)+1):
    for group in itertools.combinations(pots, num):
        patterns = zip(*[table[p] for p in group])
        counts = collections.Counter(patterns)
        for poss in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=num):
            print ', '.join(group) + ':',
            print ''.join(poss), counts[poss]
```

---

which produces:

```
PotA, PotB: ++ 3
PotA, PotB: +- 1
PotA, PotB: +? 0
PotA, PotB: -+ 0
PotA, PotB: -- 0
PotA, PotB: -? 1
PotA, PotB: ?+ 0
PotA, PotB: ?- 0
PotA, PotB: ?? 0
PotA, PotC: ++ 4
[...]
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: +++++ 3
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: ++++- 0
[...]
```

Note that I'm assuming that your desired output is in error, because in this line:

```
PotA, PotB, PotC, PotD, PotE: ++++++ 2
```

you have five columns on the left but six `+` symbols on the right.

Comment: Its an absolute shame that there's only 1 upvote, and that even comes from me... :(

Comment: Yes, that was an error so I fixed it. Thanks @DSM for the answer too. I will try it.

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine! But the memory cannot handle input data with more than 5 columns and the alphabetical pattern match '+-?'(even without '?') as the permutation goes on. Is there any supplementary code such as `del` to reduce the memory usage? Or, only permutate within the given number of columns?

Comment: @Karyo If you're having memory problems, can you post a larger data set for testing? What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @PeterGibson My actual data have 23 columns and 39 raws. For my 8Gb ram, the program runs till the calculation of the 6th column, for almost a whole day, when the memory couldn't handle the data. To test the error, just random number of columns with +s and -s will be fine. The code runs perfectly for a small number of columns, but not for a huge number of columns.